# How can I find some words in files with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have many files and need to categorize them into the words that come up there.

ex) [..murder..murderAttempted..] or [murder, murderAttempted] etc..

I tried this code. but not all came out. so I want "murder" and "murderAttmpted" in files surrounded by "[ ]".

```
def func(root_dir):
for files in os.listdir(root_dir):
    pattern = r'\[.+murder.+murderAttempted.+'
    if "txt" in files:
        f = open(root_dir + files, 'rt', encoding='UTF8')
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
                print(match.group())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for me: `pattern = r'\[.*murder.*murderAttempted.*\]'` instead of `pattern = r'\[.+murder.+murderAttempted.+'`. I believe it returns all occurrences of "murder" and "murderAttempted" in files surrounded by "[]". The `+` requires 1 or more occurrence whereas `*` could have 0. Also note the addition of the end `\]`. This ensures you only capture strings that are enclosed in brackets.